# Is my computer infected by the Recycler virus?

Tags: windows, parallels-desktop, virus

I installed Parallels Desktop for Mac and installed Windows 7. It seems like I loaded an infected file and now there are some $RECYCLER.bin folders around some places. Is this the Recycler virus? How can  I delete these files? Do I just delete the Parallels VM or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're referring to folders called $RECYCLE.bin and not RECYCLER (the latter is the recycler virus created folder).

These $RECYCLE.bin folders exist because they're created by Windows (through Parallels) because of the shared folders feature in Parallels (using which you can access folders on the other OS directly). These are not from a virus and you should just leave them as they are - they hold files/folders you delete.

This thread titled ["$RECYCLE.BIN folder created?"](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?91329-RECYCLE-BIN-folder-created) in the Parallels forum provides a concise answer from the support team:

> The $RECYCLE.BIN folder is created due to the shared folders and shared profile of Parallels.
>
> You can disable it under Virtual Machine -> Configure -> Shared Folders.

---

To make things simpler in your usage of Parallels, you may also want to explore the ["Levels of integration - Like a Mac or Like a PC"](http://kb.parallels.com/en/112146) knowledgebase article.